# Eclipse deployment descriptor not found

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jetty

I have a dynamic web project created in eclipse.  I moved the location of the WebContent folder (to be located within the /src folder).  However, the project still thinks that the directory is under `/projectName/WEB-INF/` (I know this because when I try to open an element in the deployment descriptor it tells me that that path does not exist (it doesn't exist, but I need to have it point to the new location).

How can I point the build to the new location of the WebContent folder (and WEB-INF etc.)?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click your dynamic web project -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly.

In `Web Deployment Assembly`, change the package structure to reflect your change. That should work.

Comment: I have the same problem. Your solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Windows > Show view > Project Explorer should show "deployment descriptor" again

Answer (score 5):

The original answer was unclear on the second step -- from the Web Deployment Assembly dialog, at the bottom is an **Advanced** toggle, which when opened will show the folder selection dropdown.

[image: Eclipse Deployment Assembly Property Page]

*And I intended to give a link to the Eclipse documentation for the WTP Deployment Assembly Property Page -- however I cannot find it...*

Comment: Does that Advanced section still exist? Or is it dependent on some other setting? I'm not seeing it here in 2021-06

Answer (score 2):

Go to windows > perspectives > reset perspective will possibly resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we are in default Java perspective , change it to Java EE perspective and if everything is correct then deployment descriptor is visible .

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Enterprise edition from Eclipse Market and then Install it again. My issue got solved by this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).