# Eclipse The deployment descriptor of the module 'xxx.war' cannot be loaded or found

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, web-deployment

There's been a number of similar questions raised on this error on Eclipse:

> The deployment descriptor of the module 'xxx.war' cannot be loaded or
>   found.

This is a very generic error, and after scouring the web I have multiple different causes and solutions. I'm going to attempt to list them all here, so others won't have to go through the same thing I did.

If anyone experienced other causes and solutions, please list them here too. =)

(Moderators, please wait for me to put the answer up before judging this question)

Comment: You could have posted your question along with the answer in one shot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Cause: Moved folders around**

Solution: "Right click your dynamic web project -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly.
In Web Deployment Assembly, change the package structure to reflect your change. That should work."
([Eclipse deployment descriptor not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981167/eclipse-deployment-descriptor-not-found))

**Cause: Upgraded RAD/Eclipse**

Solution A: Add and remove the module in question in application.xml (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21297984)

Solution B: Go into the file explorer and edit .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component file and make sure the dependent module is listed (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014042762)

**Cause: The dependent project has errors**

Solution: If the dependent project has errors, it will not be built into a WAR, hence can not be referenced.

**Cause: Missing web.xml**

Solution: This is a tricky one. A project with out web.xml won't show any errors (at least for me). But with out WEB-INF/web.xml file, it can't be regarded as a proper war file (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_file_format_(Sun)). Adding web.xml solved the issue.

**Cause: Wrong structure**

Solution: make sure the war file is included in the ear file. (https://community.jboss.org/thread/162761?start=0&tstart=0&_sscc=t)

**Cause: In correct facets**

Solution: 
"You must have these facets:

- Dynamic Web Module
- Java
- Websphere Web (Con-existence)
- Websphere Web (Extended)

In addition, in your Build Path -> Libraries you should have these entries:

- EAR Libraries
- JRE System Library [IBM JDK]
- Web App Libraries
- Websphere Application Server [your-ver]"
  (http://stubbisms.wordpress.com/2007/11/26/deployment-descriptor-of-the-module-yourappplicationwar-cannot-be-loaded/)

**Cause: Generic Eclipse Problem**

Solution: From time to time eclipse just stuffs up for various irrelevant reasons. To fix this, close the project, reopen, clean and recompile. Or even try it in a new work space if all else fails. (http://stubbisms.wordpress.com/2007/11/26/deployment-descriptor-of-the-module-yourappplicationwar-cannot-be-loaded/)

Comment: I have another cause, I have a few already packaged war and ejb jar files that I am including.  They are included using using maven and look like this in org.eclipse.wst.common.component:

`<dependent-module archiveName="app-root-2.0.war" deploy-path="/" handle="module:/classpath/var/M2_REPO/workspace/app/app-lib/lib/app-root.war">
            <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
</dependent-module>`

The app-root-2.0.war file is well formed with the WEB-INF folder and web.xml file

Do you have a solution for that too?  Thanks if you do!

Answer (score 1):

Had to delete the EAR from WS and disk but keep the related web projects and then checkout the EAR again. EAR deployment settings was corrupted. For anyone who has the similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I was generating "application.xml" using Maven POM and the solution for the issue was changing the maven-ear-plugin configuration like below:

```
....
<artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <version>7</version>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                <applicationName>MyCustom-ear</applicationName>
                <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
                <modules>
....
```

After changing above, delete the project or module from Eclipse (but do not delete from disk). Go to project folder from file browser (e.g. Windows Explorer) and delete .settings and target folders and .project file from the project or module and reimport the project or the module to Eclipse and it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

I had a freshly cloned project from git, I created a `EarContent` folder inside my EAR project. And I was able to add my project(EAR resource) to the Liberty server.
Manually adding `EarContent` folder which is a blank folder solver my issue.

[image]